# I'm trying to replicate this figma design

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hey I'm new into CSS but I dont know how to make this work. Please help me on how to make this work.

[image: Desired outcome]

The desired outcome.

[image: My outcome]

My outcome.

The problem is how to make the heading come under the location tags. like in the figma design?

Here is the HTML.

```
import { GrLocation } from "react-icons/gr"
<div className="container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLxQvbMyfas" className="main-img" alt="location-img" />
        <div className="tags-colum">
            <GrLocation />
            <p>JAPAN</p>
            <p className="underline-text">View on Google Maps</p>
            <div className="container-text">
                <h1>Mount Fuji</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-img {
  height: 168px;
  width: 125px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.tags-colum {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

.container-text {
  display: block;
}

.underline-text {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Why not inspect the markup of the existing site to check for differences?

Comment: please post an example with the details of GrLocation component

Comment: Add `flex-direction: columb` to `.tags-colum`

Comment: @schmauch used it but they all are stacking on each other

Comment: @FaizalHussain Please check I have updated the code

Comment: @NicoHaase This is a figma design.

Comment: I thing the problem is in another part of css. I run this css and html and there are new lines.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example for demonstrating your issue? CSS is a global thing, you might have some CSS not showing in the above question but is affecting your layout. And for how to make that heading come under the location tags, just move the `.container-text` out of `.tags-colum`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `.tags-column` is `display: flex`, so you cannot group all 3 of those elements together. Because the default flexbox is row-based style which means it will align all elements on the same row

For the fix,

1. Create a group of that left image and all content elements (`.container`)
2. Separate the location icon and `JAPAN` to another group with flexbox (`.tags-colum`)
3. Put `Mount Fuji` separately (`.container-text`)

Note that, `.new-group` is just an alias name which I'm using for demonstration, and it has no specific styles

```
import { GrLocation } from "react-icons/gr"
<div className="container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLxQvbMyfas" className="main-img" alt="location-img" />
        <div className="new-group">
           <div className="tags-colum">
              <GrLocation />
              <p>JAPAN</p>
              <p className="underline-text">View on Google Maps</p>
           </div>
           <div className="container-text">
              <h1>Mount Fuji</h1>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have used display flex to the .tags-colum ( which is the outermost parent)  to fix this you can use flex-direction: column, yes adding this will make everything stacked up, so what's the solution?
group your elements like this

```
    <div className="container">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLxQvbMyfas" className="main-img" alt="location-img" />
<div className="tags-colum">
   <div className='gp1'>
   <GrLocation />
    <p>JAPAN</p>
    <p className="underline-text">View on Google Maps</p>
     </div> 
    <div className="container-text">
        <h1>Mount Fuji</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  .tags-colum {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
    .gp1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/homepage-forked-g18lgm?file=/public/index.html:56-126

or you can completely remove the display flex from the tags-colum